# FQL searching for places by name

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

I'm kinda stuck on this FQL query.

I can get places nearby my location but sometimes the GPS is off, and I want to submit a text search for the place I'm at, but this query is not returning any result at all and it even seems that it crashes the rest of my PHP script:

```
SELECT name,description,geometry,latitude,longitude,checkin_count,display_subtext FROM place WHERE name = 'Oslo'
```

Any help's greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this unfortunately.

When I tried to query for Facebook HQ ([the correct query example from their docs page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/place/)):

[SELECT name,description,geometry,latitude, longitude, checkin_count, display_subtext FROM place WHERE name="Facebook Palo Alto"](https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20name,description,geometry,latitude,longitude,checkin_count,display_subtext%20FROM%20place%20WHERE%20name=%22Facebook%20Palo%20Alto%22&access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBAI4t7nJeLhzqLUk4H9wyATJQ3jh7BZByUGEPxevtwv5HQwDkN07sVRWjM8GIZBlOCp7Tc9UhSXcp7WQa30DH5sNOVVBwZDZD)

You get the error:

**Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql**

And if you look at the docs, the column marked with a * is only [page id](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/place/).  So you can only directly query the place table by giving it a page id.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - do you have an alternative way for me to do a text based search for a place?

Comment: subquery on page which does allow search by name?  SELECT ... from place where page_id in ( SELECT page_id from page where name = 'foo')